# Getting Some or all identity references could not be translated from NTAccount, when trying to set permissions to an AD group

Tags: c#, security, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

I'm trying to write security permissions to an Group in ActiveDirectory using C#.

**my code looks like this:**

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dudu.test.com/CN=2222,OU=Test,DC=dudu,DC=test,DC=com",adminUserName,adminUserPass);
                DirectorySearcher dsFindOUs = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);

            //    dsFindOUs.Filter = "(objectClass=group)";
             //   dsFindOUs.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                SearchResult oResults = dsFindOUs.FindOne();
                DirectoryEntry myOU = oResults.GetDirectoryEntry();

                System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("dudug").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
                ActiveDirectoryAccessRule newRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                myOU.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule(newRule); myOU.CommitChanges();
```

when i use this code, i GET a new rule added to the group, but it is called:

**"Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-1665235001-242389448-1116685.......)"**

if i change my code to this:

```
 System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("dudu.test.com","dudug").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
```

i get the error message:

```
**System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated**
```

i'm new to ActiveDirectory Code, and this is very frustrating to me,